# Rotation Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-computer

How can I rotate a state $|\psi>=\alpha|0>+\beta|1>$ to $|\psi'>=\delta|0>+\gamma|1>$ using a unitary U, where the values of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are known?

Comment: I don't get it. If you know all coeficients and both the initial and resulting states, there is nothing else there to do...

Comment: perhaps you should show research effort in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the general rotation matrix expressed in terms of Pauli matrices. Knowing which $\delta$ and $\gamma$ you need, you can find the axis of rotation to get to that state and then use the axis of rotation as a vector:
$\vec{n} = <n_{x},n_{y},n_{z}>$
In addition, you need to compute the angle $\theta$ by which you need to rotate around $\vec{n}$ to get to the needed state:

$R_{\vec{n}}(\theta) = exp (-i\frac{\theta \vec{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma}}{2})= \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})I - i\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})(n_{x}X+n_{y}Y+n_{z}Z)$

where $I,X,Y,Z$ are identity and Pauli matrices, respectively.

$R$ is your $2$x$2$ matrix of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answer: it's important to understand that, just as the rotation needed to transform a given unit vector into a second given unit vector isn't unique (you can compose the solution with any rotation about the second vector and still have a solution), so too does this problem have a nonunique solution. Recall that any $2\times 2$ unitary matrix can be written $e^{i\,\phi}\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\-b^*&a^*\end{array}\right)$ where $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$ and $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$. Then you seek such a matrix where:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}\gamma\\\delta\end{array}\right)=e^{i\,\phi}\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\-b^*&a^*\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha\\\beta\end{array}\right)$$

which can be rewritten:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}\gamma\\\delta^*\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i\,\phi}\,\alpha&e^{i\,\phi}\beta\\e^{-i\,\phi}\beta^*&-e^{-i\,\phi}\alpha^*\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\end{array}\right)$$

which you can use to find the general solution set. Exercise: why does this procedure always work (why never a singular matrix)? How does the requirements for  $|\alpha|^2+|\alpha|^2=1$, $|\gamma|^2+|\delta|^2=1$, $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$ impact on the solution(s)?